# Making the UI disappear after clicking a JButton

Tags: user-interface, jbutton

I am working on a alarm application. I want my ui to disappear when user clicks the JButton and run in the background. Can you tell me how to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. 
we just have to Call `setVisible(false)` on the frame.